Lookup unique "Values" if they follow a certain "Pattern" from a lookup table then return a "Name"
I have over 13000 unique barcode scan results stored in Sheet1 Column A. At some point similar results can occur that follows a certain pattern (out of 25 different one). The pattern can determinate a Part name. I would like to create a lookup table somewhere on Sheet2 where I could store all possible patterns and the corresponding part names. After I have set up the lookup table I would need a formula in Sheet1 Column B, dragged down that looks up each barcode scans from Column A and matches with the pattern and returns the part name from the look up table.
The following picture illustrates how I imagine the formula should work.

For confirmation purposes on another process I already created some private functions in VBA, for example:
    Function PartName4Scan(s As String) As Boolean
        PartName4Scan= s Like "225299460502#[A-Z]##[A-Z]###"
    End Function

In the other process they work perfectly when they are used individually as a certain type is meant to be in a specific cell all the time.
=IF(PartName4Scan(E34)=TRUE,"O","X").
The problem is this time, I tried embedding them into a nested IF formula as the values in Column A are in random order like this:
=IF(PartName4Scan(E34)=TRUE,"PartName4",IF(PartName5Scan(E34)=TRUE,"PartName5","X") and so on...
Of course after nesting them 3-4 times into each others I started experiencing performance issues so no way I could nest like 25 patterns together. It would be a lot easier if I can lookup the patterns and match them with the part names.

create your UDF to do all the checks and return the desired text not 25 separate ones.

@ScottCraner thank you, I would have never thought about this solution

You are so close with the function idea. You can create a user-defined function that compares all the patterns and returns the actual part name.
So in the workbook cell you can put =PartNameScan(A2) and it would return for example "Part 1"
To implement this - create a code module in your workbook and create the function something like this:
Function PartNameScan(s As String) As String
  
  If s Like "8298716602###" Then
    PartNameScan = "Part 1"
    Exit Function
  End If
    
  If s Like "225299460502#[A-Z]##[A-Z]###" Then
    PartNameScan = "Part 4"
    Exit Function
  End If
  
  'etc - add more patterns here
    
End Function


Many thanks to you too. In the meantime I started working on it after reading @Scott Craner's comment. I tried almost the same as your solution, but I forgot the "Exit Function" at the end of "if" statement so I ended up using "Select Case True" instead.

Option Compare Text
Function PartName(s As String) As String

    Select Case True
        
        Case s Like "20502#[A-Z]##[A-Z]###"
            PartName = "Part1"
        
        Case s Like "###A-Z]######"
            PartName = "Part2"
        
        Case s Like "8212-9a-zA-Z]##########"
            PartName = "Part3"
    
        Case s Like "822846######"
            PartName = "Part4"      

        'etc...
    
    End Select

End Function

